# Flutter - Accessibility error when publishing app

Tags: flutter, accessibility, store, publish

When I publish my app on the Play Store, from tests carried out I receive a recommendation on all my screens.
The following warning: The label on this item may not be read by screen readers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6rc7.png)

I already understand what an accessibility issue is and I've tried using Semantics in the code to fix it but the warning/error continues